# Write a stored procedure to update the table with some condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables.

The first table looks like this:

**##FinalTable**

```
+--------------+-----+---+
| A-LINE-ONE-1 | $10 | 1 |
+--------------+-----+---+
| A-LINE-ONE-1 | $25 | 1 |
+--------------+-----+---+
| A-LINE-ONE-1 | $51 | 1 |
+--------------+-----+---+
| A-LINE-TWO-2 | $32 | 1 |
+--------------+-----+---+
| A-LINE-TWO-2 | $22 | 1 |
+--------------+-----+---+
| A-LINE-TWO-2 | $99 | 1 |
+--------------+-----+---+
| B-LINE-ONE-3 | $71 | 1 |
+--------------+-----+---+
| B-LINE-TWO-4 | $15 | 1 |
+--------------+-----+---+
| C-LINE-ONE-5 | $17 | 1 |
+--------------+-----+---+
| C-LINE-ONE-5 | $81 | 1 |
+--------------+-----+---+
| C-LINE-TWO-6 | $51 | 1 |
+--------------+-----+---+
```

And the second table looks like this:

**##LineFormatTable**

```
+----+------------------+
| No | LINE_CODE_FORMAT |
+----+------------------+
| 1  | A-LINE           |
+----+------------------+
| 2  | B-LINE           |
+----+------------------+
| 3  | C-LINE           |
+----+------------------+
```

I want to update the first table (`##FinalTable`) if `LINE_CODE` is getting repeated then increment `TAB_NUM` by one and if the `LINE_CODE_FORMAT` gets changed then increment the `TAB_NUM`.

This is the desired result:

```
+--------------+------------+---------+
| LINE_CODE    | LINE_VALUE | TAB_NUM |
+--------------+------------+---------+
| A-LINE-ONE-1 | $10        | 1       |
+--------------+------------+---------+
| A-LINE-ONE-1 | $25        | 2       |
+--------------+------------+---------+
| A-LINE-ONE-1 | $51        | 3       |
+--------------+------------+---------+
| A-LINE-TWO-2 | $32        | 1       |
+--------------+------------+---------+
| A-LINE-TWO-2 | $22        | 2       |
+--------------+------------+---------+
| A-LINE-TWO-2 | $99        | 3       |
+--------------+------------+---------+
| B-LINE-ONE-3 | $71        | 4       |
+--------------+------------+---------+
| B-LINE-TWO-4 | $15        | 4       |
+--------------+------------+---------+
| C-LINE-ONE-5 | $17        | 5       |
+--------------+------------+---------+
| C-LINE-ONE-5 | $81        | 6       |
+--------------+------------+---------+
| C-LINE-ONE-6 | $51        | 6       |
+--------------+------------+---------+
```

I want to write a stored procedure that updates `##FinalTable`.

I have tried like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##FinalTable') IS NOT NULL
    TRUNCATE TABLE ##FinalTable
ELSE  
    CREATE TABLE ##FinalTable 
    (
        LINE_CODE varchar(20), 
        LINE_VALUE varchar(50),
        TAB_NUM int
    )
 

INSERT INTO ##FinalTable 
VALUES ('A-LINE-ONE-1', '$10', 1),
       ('A-LINE-ONE-1', '$25', 1),
       ('A-LINE-ONE-1', '$51', 1),
       ('A-LINE-TWO-2', '$32', 1),
       ('A-LINE-TWO-2', '$22', 1),
       ('A-LINE-TWO-2', '$99', 1),
       ('B-LINE-ONE-3', '$71', 1),
       ('B-LINE-TWO-4', '$15', 1),
       ('C-LINE-ONE-5', '$17', 1),
       ('C-LINE-ONE-5', '$81', 1),
       ('C-LINE-TWO-6', '$51', 1)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##LineFormatTable') IS NOT NULL
    TRUNCATE TABLE ##LineFormatTable
ELSE  
    CREATE TABLE ##LineFormatTable
    (
         No int identity(1,1),      
         LINE_CODE_FORMAT varchar(50)
    )

INSERT INTO ##LineFormatTable 
VALUES ('A-LINE'),
       ('B-LINE'),
       ('C-LINE')

DECLARE @LineFormatCount INT=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ##LineFormatTable)
DECLARE @TabNum INT = 0
DECLARE @i INT = 1;
DECLARE @CurrentLineNum INT=1
DECLARE @CurrentTabCode varchar(50)

WHILE @LineFormatCount >= @i
BEGIN
    SELECT @CurrentTabCode=LINE_CODE_FORMAT from ##LineFormatTable where No = @i;
    
    WITH CTE_ONE AS 
         (SELECT *,  
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LINE_CODE) AS ROW_NUMBER, 
            COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY LINE_CODE) AS LINE_COUNT 
         FROM ##FinalTable)
    UPDATE CTE_ONE 
         SET CTE_ONE.TAB_NUM = CASE when ROW_NUMBER > LINE_COUNT THEN ABS(ROW_NUMBER-LINE_COUNT) + @TabNum else @TabNum  + CTE_ONE.ROW_NUMBER  end
         WHERE LINE_CODE like '%'+ @CurrentTabCode +'-%' and (LINE_COUNT > 1 or @TabNum <> CTE_ONE.TAB_NUM);

         SET @LineFormatCount =(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ##LineFormatTable)
         SET @TabNum = (SELECT MAX(TAB_NUM) FROM ##FinalTable WHERE LINE_CODE like '%'+ @CurrentTabCode +'-%')
         select  @TabNum 
         SET @i = @i+1
END
```

Here when the `LINE_CODE_FORMAT` is getting changed, the `TAB_NUM` is not properly getting update.

Comment: How come B-LINE-ONE-3 gets the same tab_num as B-LINE-TWO-4 when the line_code has changed

Comment: When Line_Format is changed or Line_Code is repeated then only Tab_Num will change. In B-Line-One-3 and B-Line-One-4 the format is not changed and it is not repeated one so Tab_Nub will not change.@P.Salmon

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LINE_CODE ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##FinalTable') IS NOT NULL
  TRUNCATE TABLE ##FinalTable
ELSE  
    CREATE TABLE ##FinalTable (
    LINE_CODE varchar(20), 
    LINE_VALUE varchar(50),
    TAB_NUM int) 

INSERT INTO ##FinalTable VALUES ('A-LINE-ONE-1', '$10', 1),
       ('A-LINE-ONE-1', '$25', 1),
       ('A-LINE-ONE-1', '$51', 1),
       ('A-LINE-TWO-2', '$32', 1),
       ('A-LINE-TWO-2', '$22', 1),
       ('A-LINE-TWO-2', '$99', 1),
       ('B-LINE-ONE-3', '$71', 1),
       ('B-LINE-TWO-4', '$15', 1),
       ('C-LINE-ONE-5', '$17', 1),
       ('C-LINE-ONE-5', '$81', 1),
       ('C-LINE-TWO-6', '$51', 1)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##LineFormatTable') IS NOT NULL
    TRUNCATE TABLE ##LineFormatTable
ELSE  
    CREATE TABLE ##LineFormatTable
    (No int identity(1,1),      
     LINE_CODE_FORMAT varchar(50))

INSERT INTO ##LineFormatTable VALUES ('A-LINE'),
                                     ('B-LINE'),
                                     ('C-LINE')

DECLARE @LineFormatCount INT=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ##LineFormatTable)
DECLARE @TabNum INT = 0
DECLARE @i INT = 1;
DECLARE @CurrentLineNum INT=1
DECLARE @CurrentTabCode varchar(50)

WHILE @LineFormatCount >= @i
BEGIN
    SELECT @CurrentTabCode=LINE_CODE_FORMAT from ##LineFormatTable where No = @i;

    WITH CTE_ONE AS 
         (SELECT *,  
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LINE_CODE) AS ROW_NUMBER, 
            COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY LINE_CODE) AS LINE_COUNT 
         FROM ##FinalTable WHERE LINE_CODE like '%'+ @CurrentTabCode +'-%')
    UPDATE CTE_ONE 
         SET CTE_ONE.TAB_NUM = CASE when ROW_NUMBER > LINE_COUNT THEN ABS(ROW_NUMBER-LINE_COUNT) + @TabNum else @TabNum  + CTE_ONE.ROW_NUMBER  end
          WHERE (LINE_COUNT > 1 or @TabNum <> CTE_ONE.TAB_NUM);

         SET @LineFormatCount =(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ##LineFormatTable)
         SET @TabNum = (SELECT MAX(TAB_NUM) FROM ##FinalTable WHERE LINE_CODE like '%'+ @CurrentTabCode +'-%')
         SET @i = @i+1
END
```

If anyone have other optimized query or want to update this one is appreciated.

Comment: Is this an answer? You should only post answers in the answer box.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).